# SQL Jobs Schedule to Not Run on Holidays

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent Job that has multiple steps which are scheduled to run Monday - Friday at a certain time.  I need to be able to implement a stop feature on this job to not run on Holidays that are listed in a table.

I don't really know how to proceed with this.  Do I need to create a first step that checks if it is a holiday and then fails the job if it is?

I have a stored procedure that will check the date that I pass to see if it is a holiday, I just don't know how to force it to report failure if the result is yes it is a holiday.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to actively fail? Or just quietly stop?

Comment: I guess just quietly stop. I need it to stop the process for that day but it will pick up the regular schedule the next day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea:

1. SQL Server Agent runs job
2. 1st step is "check for holiday"
3. code throws error
4. job step silently fails

Point 3: To get the error from from the stored procedure to SQL Server Agent, you use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

```
...
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE Date = GETDATE())
   RAISERROR ('Do nothing: relax: chill out', 16, 1);
...
```

Points 4: In this case, use "Quit with success" (1) for the `@on_fail_action` parameter to [sp_add_jobstep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx)

Comment: is the sp_add_jobstep located in msdb, if so I am not sure that I can use that because our servers are pretty much locked down to use only the database we can access.

Comment: @bluefeet: sp_add_jobstep is also run when the job is set up in SSMS

Comment: sorry for not understanding, I am new to setting up jobs, etc.  I guess I am missing something. In my step to Check for Holiday, I execute the stored proc which I updated to include RAISERROR. I don't see where the sp_add_jobstep comes in with this step.

Comment: The GUI calls sp_add_jobstep. In the GUI there is an option to choose what happens on failure etc. I don't have SQL Server installed here to take screen shots

Comment: I get it now but I must be doing something wrong.   I added today's date to my Holiday table and ran it.  The process stopped as expected after the Check for Holiday. But when I removed today's date and ran it again it never got to the second step.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I had to change the way I was passing in my date - getdate() wasn't working.  thanks so much for the help.